# VBA Userform Object - Defining runtime created Label as a common name to use in sub

Tags: vba, object, runtime, userform

I have a userform that creates 20-30 labels upon initalization. At the same time a listbox is filled with the name of all these labels.

I want the user to select the label from the listbox which will 'activate' that label by defining it as ActiveTB. Then I will be able to run the following code to move that label around on the userform.

[image]

If i only had 3 labels: Label1, label2, label3 - I could just copy and paste this code below and have ActiveTB replaced with their names. However this is rediculous for 30 labels, and i also don't know what the names of these labels will be (there is a rename function in there).

I'm sure this is a simple fix but i can't find a way to call an object via a commonly activated name.

```
Private Sub ActiveTB_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    If Button = 1 Then
        m_sngLeftPos = X
        m_sngTopPos = Y
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ActiveTB_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Dim sngLeft As Single
    Dim sngTop As Single

    If Button = 1 Then
        With ActiveTB
            sngLeft = .Left + X - m_sngLeftPos
            If sngLeft < SeriesImage.Left Then sngLeft = SeriesImage.Left
            If (sngLeft + .Width) > (SeriesImage.Left + SeriesImage.Width) Then
                sngLeft = SeriesImage.Left + SeriesImage.Width - .Width
            End If
            sngTop = .Top + Y - m_sngTopPos
            If sngTop < SeriesImage.Top Then sngTop = SeriesImage.Top
            If (sngTop + .Height) > (SeriesImage.Top + SeriesImage.Height) Then
                sngTop = SeriesImage.Top + SeriesImage.Height - .Height
            End If
            .Move sngLeft, sngTop
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable declared using `WithEvents` and set that to the label corresponding to the user's listbox selection.

Here's a simple example with just two labels - each one is "set" by a separate button:

```
Private WithEvents ActiveLabel As MSForms.Label '<< ######
Dim m_sngLeftPos, m_sngTopPos

'activate label1
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set ActiveLabel = Me.Label1
End Sub

'activate label2
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Set ActiveLabel = Me.Label2
End Sub

Private Sub ActiveLabel_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, _
            ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Button = 1 Then
        m_sngLeftPos = X
        m_sngTopPos = Y
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ActiveLabel_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, _
             ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Dim sngLeft As Single
    Dim sngTop As Single

    If Button = 1 Then
        With ActiveLabel
            sngLeft = .Left + X - m_sngLeftPos
            If sngLeft < SeriesImage.Left Then sngLeft = SeriesImage.Left
            If (sngLeft + .Width) > (SeriesImage.Left + SeriesImage.Width) Then
                sngLeft = SeriesImage.Left + SeriesImage.Width - .Width
            End If
            sngTop = .Top + Y - m_sngTopPos
            If sngTop < SeriesImage.Top Then sngTop = SeriesImage.Top
            If (sngTop + .Height) > (SeriesImage.Top + SeriesImage.Height) Then
                sngTop = SeriesImage.Top + SeriesImage.Height - .Height
            End If
            .Move sngLeft, sngTop
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```